# option selected doesn't show in Android device

Tags: android, css, html

Anyone know why selected   attributes don't show in android device.It's work well in iOS.

[image]

```
<select class="golden-mobile" >

 <option selected="selected" >More Info...</option>
 <option value="http://tshproperty.com/golden-visa/what-is-the-golden-visa/">What's Golden Visa?</option> 
 <option value="http://tshproperty.com/golden-visa/golden-visa-general-requirements/">General Requirements</option>
 <option value="http://tshproperty.com/golden-visa/spain/top-5-reasons-to-invest-in-spain/">Top 5 Reasons to Invest In Spain</option>
 <option value="http://tshproperty.com/golden-visa/spain/faq-spanish-golden-visa/">FAQs</option>
 <option value="http://tshproperty.com/golden-visa/spain/torrevieja/">Torrevieja</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string.xml would be :

```
<resources>
        <string name="country_prompt">Choose a country</string>

    <string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

and you main_activity.xml

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />
```

when you select any option from Spinner it will show over there.
and you can use **onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos,long id)** for an fire any Action.